# The optimal way of improving fluency in elementary maths techniques, whilst holding a 9-5 job?

Tags: experimental-mathematics, mental-arithmetic

As an example of someone who has discovered maths at a later point in my life than average, and who has (perhaps unusually?) proven the point that it is perfectly possible to study undergraduate mathematics with almost no prerequisites, I am now having to accept that fluency in mathematical techniques is in the end extremely important in the long run.

I am curious about the extent to which having a rich exposure to elementary maths techniques must influence creativity in research later on? At the moment I have taken on a full-time programming job, and I am looking for optimal methods for improving fluency in elementary maths, that could work in such a limited time frame. Any suggestions? Could it be feasible to multi-task- say, for example, practice methods of mental arithmetic at the same time as doing something else?

Comment: You will have to set aside a block of uninterrupted time every day to focus on studying mathematics. It won't help to squeeze in a minute here and a minute there, or to multitask. Your attention must be devoted to the subject for a block of time on a regular basis. Even one hour daily will do (longer would be better). Weekends and holidays offer the possibility of several hours. But **you** have to make it a priority and not let the demands of others override your decision to devote your time to this. Discipline is the key to advancement.

Comment: (Continued from above) I work full time and have done something similar. You can try getting up an hour earlier in the morning, or going to bed an hour later in the evening, to give you the time you need. Or study through lunch. Take a vacation day now and then, and use it to study instead of taking a real vacation. I know it sounds tough, but the simple fact is that it **is** tough. You have to make up your mind that you are going to do that. You, and only you, can make this happen--but it won't happen if it's not a priority.